# Is this a type of nominalism?

Tags: structuralism, nominalism

Abstract entities do not exist, but their absences from each other, do, concretely. Is that a type of nominalism?

So the numbers five and four do not exist, but four not being five, is a concrete (I guess structural) feature of the world

Comment: [Neo-logicists](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/abstract-objects/#WayAbst) get something like this with their use of Hume's and other abstraction principles. But they consider themselves platonists even though their abstract objects proper (like numbers) are just functional, and hence, to a degree, nominal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a type of nominalism. Realism with respect to some noun "X" asserts that "X exists" or "X is real". Nominalism asserts that " 'X' is just a name, but does not 'exist' or is not 'real' ". Thus, by asserting that numbers do not exist, one is asserting nominalism with respect to numbers, hence, one is asserting a form of nominalism.

Comment: Does it have a name? Cheers

Comment: Usually, when one holds that numbers do not exist, one also holds that there are other nouns, "X", such that "X does not exist", and hence there isn't a "school of numeric nominalism". It is too narrow a position to deserve the title of a school. But if one wants to describe how one views numbers in particular, then I think "numeric" or "mathematical" nominalism is appropriate. Although I don't recall ever hearing such terms, I think most philosophers would quickly understand what was meant.

Comment: The caveat, then, that about overlapping absences existing, is common to all (or most?) nominalism? I think perhaps my question is so ill informed that it has been misunderstood.

Comment: I found a link, thanks for your encouragement

Comment: That is not what is usually meant by nominalism.

Answer (score 1):

Surely, it's nominalism as you're certainly playing a kind of word game here, that's all you can get from debating the difference between nominalism and realism.

Their only difference is how they define the word "exists". If two equal saints meet and argue about something, most likely u should bet they're both honest, smart and wise guy, just confused about each other's definition. This universal confusion caused so many unnecessary conflicts throughout history. As Socrates once hinted that debate is not to defeat anyone's judgement, but is an efficient way to sort out each other's confusions and quickly lead to the always-escaping elusive truth...

The Problem of "Universals" is such an ancient typical conflict, now I think every sensible person will agree there exists a necessary mathematical concept called "2" after seeing two seemingly identical things. The only critical insight in this simple-yet-seemingly-philosophically-deep problem is that all human concepts/definitions are relative, meaning the concept "exists" itself is relative to a certain layer of our mind... "2" is certainly more abstract than "pain" which our body can feel impressively while a number, not so much due to our biological design. While certain math genius may feel "2" more impressively than "pain", and that's why this person can surely outperforms you in solving Math number theory problems in the long run as a persistent game, unless somehow later you acquired more intuition after huge effort and struggle...The most hard part is when most people say something "exists" they implicitly assume there's an absolute background reference frame in which there's an objective yes or no binary judgement can be made. And most of them will be satisfied spending all their life arguing about this type of "wonderous" existence and that kind of "pitiful" nonsense, essentially much like machine, they'll keep their focus on these outward worldly existences to try to "prove" or "disprove" from their experiences as a vanity show to others. While for those rare illuminated and awaken people, inward retrospect and self-reflection is much more important than those outside existence or not. They fully understand when indulging in outward existence discussion the endgame is just to find a place for inward sentiment to attach. Neither outward realism nor nominalism is all the truth, they're just a small part of it to stimulate and invoke your inward "intellect memory sea", which in some religious factions it's called “the Eight Consciousnesses”. it's beyond common outward/inward perceptions, ego and comprehensions, similar to western world's subconsciousness notion. So the whole truth remains extremely hidden and mystically elusive in this vast sea of pictorial metaphors, no two persons will share exactly same images to the same clarity degree, not even nowadays super AI/GPT3 can sort out completely. Thus to understand and progress oneself accordingly is the ultimate goal and the only important truth for oneself...

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is, simply due to the fact that you say they do exist *as concretes*. See [the SEP entry on nominalism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/nominalism-metaphysics/#WhaNom):

> Nominalism is not simply the rejection of universals or abstract objects. For if that were the case, a nihilist, someone who believed that there are no entities at all, would count as a nominalist. Similarly, someone who rejected universals or abstract objects but were agnostic about the existence of particulars or concrete objects would count as a nominalist. Given how the term ‘Nominalism’ is used in contemporary philosophy, such philosophers would not be nominalists. **The word ‘Nominalism’ carries an implication that the corresponding doctrine asserts that everything is particular or concrete, and that this is not vacuously true.**

> Thus one kind of Nominalism asserts that there are particular objects and that everything is particular, and the other asserts that there are concrete objects and that everything is concrete.

Your proposal is to say that numbers themselves as abstract objects do not exist but their relations do, as concretes. This follows a standard strategy of nominalism to be able to assert at least some structural features as really existing:

> But what does Nominalism claim with respect to the entities alleged by some to be universals or abstract objects, e.g. properties, numbers, propositions, possible worlds? Here there are two general options: (a) to deny the existence of the alleged entities in question, and (b) to accept the existence of these entities but to argue that they are particular or concrete.

Having said that, your "theory" does not involve any argument for them being concrete.

Answer (score 0):

There are many varieties of *mathematical* structuralism, and I do not know what a structuralism of all abstract entities would be.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/structuralism-mathematics/

1.

> All the variants of structuralism described up to this point are forms
> of “philosophical structuralism”, or more precisely, of “**metaphysical
> structuralism**”. What that means is that these positions are intended
> to provide answers to questions about what mathematical structures are
> (even when this involves an eliminative stance), including views about
> their existence, abstractness, identity, dependence, etc. Now, one can
> distinguish this whole variety of philosophical positions from what is
> sometimes called “mathematical structuralism”, or again more
> precisely, “methodological structuralism”... As its name suggests,
> methodological structuralism concerns the methodology of mathematics,
> thus mathematical practice. Or as one might also put it, it concerns a
> certain “style” of doing mathematics.

2. 

> Hellman’s position is meant to be a form of **nominalism**, i.e., to
> eliminate the appeal to any kind of abstract entity (not only abstract
> structures but also sets etc.).

3. 

> there are “**eliminative**” forms of structuralism, as illustrated paradigmatically by Hellman; and there are “non-eliminative” forms of structuralism, like Shapiro’s. (The elimination at issue concerns the postulation, or avoidance thereof, of structures as abstract objects.)

4. 

> there are **fully** eliminatavist positions...

5. 

> we can include Julius Caesar or some beer mug in our domain, with the
> consequence that either of them can “be” the number 2, say, in the
> sense of taking up the “2-position” in the model for arithmetic we
> choose to work with. Because of this feature, we will use “**relativist**
> structuralism” for this approach... Should relativist structuralism in general... be seen as cases of in re structuralism, in the sense that abstract structure exist “in” their more concrete instantiations? Perhaps

---

I'm looking for a **fully eliminativist nominalist relativist metaphysical structuralism**

Which does not seem to have an example in the article, thought neither does it seem to be impossible therein.